# ng-class not evaluating the expression

Tags: angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to implement ng-class in my angularJs application but for some reason expression in the ng-class is not getting applied, any thoughts?

```
<span>{{prod.item.count}}</span>

<div ng-class="{'show-error-box' : prod.item.length< 1}" class="hide-error-box">
```

prod is my controller alias in the view and item is the scope object in my controller

I want the class 'show-error-box' when the number of items is less than 1 otherwise apply the class hide-error-box. As I don't have any test data to test this with 0 length i'm replacing the expression with ng-class="{'show-error-box' : 0< 1}" in which case show-error-box should get applied, but it is not happening.

- CSS:

  .hide-error-box {
  display:none;
  }

  .show-error-box {
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10% 0;
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  }

Answer (score 2):

ng-class does not serve as a replacement to "class". It will add any classes whose name is a key in your object if the associated value is true.

The only two options this div will have as a result are:

```
class="hide-error-box"
```

or

```
class="hide-error-box show-error-box"
```

To acheive the desired effect you would could put the opposite condition as a value of your hide class.

```
ng-class="{hide-error-box: prod.item.length >= 1, show-error-box: prod.item.length < 1}"
```

However, it is often recommended that you keep your templates as free from logic as possible. It may be worth considering placing this in a controller function:

HTML

`<div class="{{getSizeClass()}}">`

JS

`this.getSizeClass = function() {
    if (item.length >= 1) {
        return 'hide-error-box'
    }
    return 'show-error-box'
}`

Comment: In your solution, you need to surround the style name with single quotes because it has dashes in it.